# Equation number not in the same line with my equation

Tags: equations

I'm new here, and I'm learning how to use LATEX. Please, I have a small problem in that the equation number appears an a new line. That is, it is not on the same line as the equation.

```
\begin{equation}
f(l) = a_i*(l-x_i)+y_i     \hspace{1cm}     x_i\leq l\geq x_n
\end{equation}
```

Comment: you can not have a blank line in an equation (you should have seen an error message)

Comment: It's not normal to use `*` for multiplication, normally nothing or `\times` or `\cdot`

Comment: Thank you for replying, I checked the message, and there is error saying (Display math should end with $$) where can I add this symbol please

Comment: You cannot have a blank line in an equation, as David has said. Delete the blank lines and the error should go away.

Comment: No that is exactly the error you get for having a blank line, just remove the blank lines. In general if you get any error do not ask about the form of the typeset result, TeX's recovery after an error is designed to let the code carry on, it is not designed to produce sensible typeset output.

Comment: problem solved. Thank you very much for your help, your advice helped me and saved my time ....regards,